# How to get a oauth access token created in owin API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, owin

I need to extract the generated token and store it in database. 

Is there any way in OAuth 2.0 to get the generated token before it is being sent in response?
 
or Is there way to analyse response sent by owin api on authentication?

Answer (score 3):

Noticed that no one answered this question yet and I was looking for an answer myself!

Eventually figured it out, so here is my first contribution to StackOverflow!

I'm using a custom class (SimpleAuthProvider) for my OWIN middleware:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions();
oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token");
oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.Provider = new SimpleAuthProvider();
```

Please note this class I have declared in my project:

```
public class SimpleAuthProvider:OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
```

A part of Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth!  I'll assume you are using the same, but the approach may be similar across OAuth implementations.

To get the token and store it in the database, override the following:

```
    public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext ctx) {
      //...get _customer database context (in my case, this happens earlier)
      _customer.LastIssuedToken = ctx.AccessToken;
      _db.SaveChanges();
      return base.TokenEndpointResponse(ctx);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dunlavy. The TokenEndpointResponse method is not available in OAuth 2, its there from OAuth 3.

Comment: I looked at the assembly I'm using and it is Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll, v3.0.1.0.  So you're right on that.  Is upgrading via Nuget not an option?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I am looking for :)

Comment: is there anyway for oauth2.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 2.1.0, Then you have to update it using Nuget Package manager to 3.0.0(BTW I'm using 3.1.0 and working fine) . TokenEndpointResponse and OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext is not available in 2.0. Then use this function and you'll get value in context.

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
 {
   string token = context.AccessToken;
   return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
 }
```